# Where can I find major appliance failure data?

Tags: usa, machine-learning

I am looking for data which gives details about when a major appliance like refrigerator, dishwasher, washing machine, TV failed and what was the cause. Further, details like

- When the product was purchased
- When it failed
- Daily usage
- If a repair was attempted
- How many repairs in past
- Repair resolution

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330246301_Understanding_lifetimes_and_failure_modes_of_defective_washing_machines_and_dishwashers